# Font size in running app not same as in storyboard (Xcode 14.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, xcode14

The font size displayed when running the app is smaller than what I have set in the storyboard.
After doing some digging it is my understanding there was a button called "Adjusts Font For Content Size Category" in previous Xcode versions, that would help me get the result I want.
But I cannot find "Adjusts Font For Content Size Category" in Xcode 14.1.

Any solutions to this?

[image]

Comment: In your example you are using Large Title which is defined by the system. For these kind of font , the system can make them bigger or smaller with the accessibility parameters. If you want to set the size by yourself, you must choose a font like Helvetica or any other named font and adjust its size, then you can also set a minimum size (or scale) in case there is not enough space.

Comment: But how can the system make them bigger? How do I set this in the storyboard?

Comment: I think this may not be possible for Button. You may have to choose specific font/size.

Answer (score 0):

In xCode 14 "Adjusts font size for category" has been replaced by the "Adjusts Font" property. You can find it in the attribute inspector for a UILabel or in your case your Button.

You just have to click the T icon to the right of the font label.
When the dialog opens, just use the "Size" slider or enter a value.

Do not forget after to enable the "Adjusts Font" checkbox.

Comment: Can you please narrow down where I can find the "Adjusts Front" checkbox? I attached an image of my attribute inspector.

Comment: In the box where there is your text « Large Title » you can click on the « T » on the right of the text, you should see what I described

Comment: So I have no problem with entering a value via the T icon, where I can choose font and font size, again this is no problem at all. But what I am still not finding is the "Adjusts Font" checkbox. Where is this checkbox?